# Accesing Opportunity Object ID

Tags: visualforce, opportunity, salesforce-id

I am trying to access the object id of Opportunity. Is there a way I can do this from within a Visualforce page?

Just to be clear I am looking for the id of the actual object not the ids of it's records.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be clearer, what do you mean by Object ID if you don't mean the ID of an opportunity record.

Comment: Are you referring to the first 3 characters of the salesforce record id, like 006 for the opportunity object?

Answer (score 2):

If the visualforce page has access to the record id, you can just grab the first 3 characters, from the [help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005995&language=en_US) docs here:

> Every ID in the App is either 15 characters or 18 characters (API).
>   The first 3-digits of the ID is always the Entity ID...